# How to deploy wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application which contains another wpf application. On the click of the button 2nd wpf application launches which uses some images stored in Image folder in my project. Everything works fine in visual studio, but when I publish my application using Build>Publish I get application stop working when I click on button to open that 2nd wpf application. How to perfectly deploy application which contains some images? I didn't try Installshield because there is an error in registration process.

Comment: Are the images exported as resources or are they located in the output folder? Chances are the publishing builds to another folder in which the images are not located.

Comment: .Net applications can usually be installed by using XCopy, so I doubt that the problem is related to the installer. What you can do is copy the wpf project to a different folder and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got installshield & created installer using installshield. @Bauss yes there was problem with image folder which i fixed it.